# Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of simple type, missing type id property type

Tags: java, spring, jackson, marshalling, junit5

I am trying to write a JUNIT for my serialization class .Version i am using for jackson is jackson-databind-2.10.2 My Concrete class extends and abstract class . When i am running my JUNIT i am getting an exception, Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type,ReshipInfo]: missing type id property 'type'
Below is my JSON to serialize . What i am missing. Please help.

```
{
 "orderId" : "12345",
 "orderDocumentType" : "SALES"
}
```

**JUNIT Call**

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samples/response.json");
String control = IOUtils.toString(is, Charsets.UTF_8);
ReshipInfo reshipInfo = objectMapper.readValue(control, ReshipInfo.class);
```

**Concrete Class**

```
 public class ReshipInfo extends AbstractRequest {
 private Integer returnGracePeriod;
 public ReshipInfo() {
 }
 public ReshipInfo(Builder builder) {
    super(builder.orderDocumentType);       
    returnGracePeriod = builder.returnGracePeriod;

 }
 }
```

**Abstract Class**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ReshipInfo.class, name = "SALES")
})
public abstract class AbstractRequest {
@JsonProperty(value = "type")
private OrderDocumentType orderDocumentType;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an abstract class (in your case - AbstractRequest) while config SetupContext of Jackson.
Like:
`context.setMixInAnnotations(ReshipInfo.class, AbstractRequest.class)`

So my entity extends ReshipInfo as abstract, and ReshipInfo does not extend AbstractRequest.